# VIM: how to make the 'saveas' browse window filetype to be .txt

Tags: vim

When I open a new empty buffer in VIM (on Windows), I am usually writing a note to myself.  How can I make the default file type in the Save As browse window, be `.txt`?

I tried setting browsefilter to no avail:

```
:let b:browsefilter="Text\t*.txt\n"
```

Suggestions?

**EDIT**:  I've just about given up.  I broke down and looked in the GVIM 7 source code - in "`gui_gtk.c`" it has the following:

```
 /*
  * Put up a file requester.
  * Returns the selected name in allocated memory, or NULL for Cancel.
  * saving,         select file to write
  * title           title for the window
  * dflt                default name
  * ext             not used (extension added)
  * initdir         initial directory, NULL for current dir
  * filter          not used (file name filter)
  */
     char_u *
 gui_mch_browse(int saving UNUSED,
           char_u *title,
           char_u *dflt,
           char_u *ext UNUSED,
           char_u *initdir,
           char_u *filter UNUSED)
 {
```

This suggests to me that the function which does the GUI prompt for browsing to save, explicitly says it ignores a `ext` argument - so I can't specify a default type.

I've settled on an awful custom save command with a pre-prompt for filename that comes before the actual SaveAs command - so *ad hoc* that I blush to include it here.

Thanks anyway, folks.

Answer (score 1):

You were close the `b:` needs to be `g:`.:

```
:let g:browsefilter="Text\t*.txt\n"
```

Comment: It can be either global, `g` or local to a buffer, `b`. However in this case I imagine `g:browsefilter` is what is being desired. See `:h browsefilter` for more information. If you want to learn more about vim's variable scheme please see `:h internal-variables`

Comment: This didn't change the behavior.  I did the above, did `File->Save As`, entered `hello`, and vim named the file `hello` (I'm shooting for `hello.txt`).

Comment: For what it's worth, we might be using the wrong mechanism - even the name suggests it's a way to filter files that I'm looking for, rather than to give a default (type) attribute to a file I'm creating.  Does anyone out there know the VIM code well enough to steer us in the right direction?